# Is Java Reflection bad practice?

Tags: java, javafx, reflection

Consider this piece of code:

```
public void doSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String query = searchTextField.getText();
    if (query.isEmpty()) {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dc.getJobCoachRepo().getList());
        usersTableView.setItems(data);
    } else {

        String searchOn = "search" + searchChoiceBox.getValue();
        try {
            Method m = this.getClass().getMethod(searchOn, String.class);
            m.invoke(this, query);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

public void searchFirstName(String query) {
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dc.getJobCoachRepo().searchFirstName(query));
    usersTableView.setItems(data);

}
...
...
```

I'm using java reflection here to avoid an if construct. The choicebox is used to let the user decide on what attribute he wants to search, there are 6 possibilities right now. I've gotten some comments from other students that using reflection is 'bad practice'. Is this the case? Why?

Comment: It's very bad because it ties your UI to your method names, which should be completely unrelated. Making an seemingly innocent change later on can have unexpected disastrous consequences.

Comment: Using reflection is not a bad practice. *Doing this sort of thing* is a bad practice. A better approach when you're wanting to pick among several similar objects by ID is a map from string to a strategy object.

Comment: @shmosel It's not necessarily that they're tied, but that they're tied so opaquely.

Comment: I would love the look on your face when you're asked to add an option to run the UI in a different (human) language....

Comment: So, totally overturning the question: in which cases reflection is acceptable, good or even recommended practice?

Comment: Yes, it is: https://www.yegor256.com/2015/04/02/class-casting-is-anti-pattern.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many reasons this is bad practice. Among them:

1. It is not robust. The text that the user types in the text field has to match the name of a method, which implies a horrendous level of coupling between things that should not be related at all
2. Reflection performs badly. Probably not a big deal here, but if there is no good reason to use reflection, you shouldn't.
3. There is a ready-made better solution using lambda expressions.

Consider instead populating your combo box with `Consumer<String>` objects:

```
ComboBox<Consumer<String>> searchChoiceBox = new ComboBox<>();
searchChoiceBox.getItems().add(createSearchOption(this::searchFirstName, "First Name"));

// ...

private Consumer<String> createSearchOption(Consumer<String> search, String name) {
    return new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) {
            search.accept(s);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name ;
        }
    };
}
```

Then you just do:

```
public void doSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String query = searchTextField.getText();
    if (query.isEmpty()) {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dc.getJobCoachRepo().getList());
        usersTableView.setItems(data);
    } else {

        searchChoiceBox.getValue().accept(query);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, reflection is slow, and it creates fragile code when used in this way.

If you want to avoid the if statement, you should use polymorphism. Create an interface `Searcher` with `public void search(String query)`, create implementations for every type of search you want to do, and then put an instance of each implementation as the value of a `Map<String, Searcher>`, keyed by the value of the search choice box.

Because Java enums are objects, you could also use an enum as your map. Each enum value would define their own `search(string)` implementation. You could then call the implementation you want using `SearchEnumTypeName.valueOf(searchChoiceBox.getValue()).search(query)`

Answer (score 1):

### Native Image creation

If the world of [Ahead of Time Compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) with GraalVM interests you (which is receiving more interest in the world of microservices), I can tell you that reflection is the biggest barrier. And in my opinion it's unnecessary.

You have to identify classes manually (via reflection.json) that the Java linker has to retain as it tries to reduce unused code bloating the binary.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly:

> Is Java Reflection bad practice?

No. It is a feature of the language and necessary under some circumstances. At a very high level, it is a valid form of developer API between separately compiled codebases. In other words, if you include third-party code, there may be objects exposed from that code that do not expose any API other than their type or existence of attributes for determining details about the data that was passed in and how to handle it downstream. This *may* require you to either choose between using reflection or discarding the library. It is not "bad practice" to choose the former.

PS: Happy to supply a code snippet if this is not clear