Why does pattern matching with switch on InetAddress fail with 'does not cover all possible input values'?
In Java 21 and 23, java.net.InetAddress is declared
public sealed class InetAddress implements Serializable permits Inet4Address, Inet6Address {

However, the following code:
switch (addr) {
     case Inet4Address a -> ...;
     case Inet6Address a -> ...;
};

does not compile with:
the switch expression does not cover all possible input values

Am I missing something, or is this a Java bug?

What if addr is null?

@MatsLindh pattern switch is defined to have an implicit case null -> throw NullPointerException()

@Turing85 Doh, of course

@Turing85 Post an answer next time. I can't accept my own answer.

The code provided is missing a case for InetAddress itself:
InetAddress foo = null;
System.out.println(switch (foo) {
  case Inet4Address unused -> "Inet4Address";
  case Inet6Address unused -> "Inet6Address";
  case InetAddress unused -> "InetAddress";
});

Notice that we want to put InetAddress as last case since it would otherwise make the other two cases unreachable.

Thanks. I instinctively assumed InetAddress was abstract, but it's an ugly OOP situation born out of backward compatibility where InetAddress is functionally same as Inet4Address. Inet6Address and Inet4Address were added in Java 1.4.

Ok, I'm still going to call it a "JDK bug." I don't see a reason InetAddress couldn't be abstract. Its constructor is package-private. I guess they were just too lazy to change the one place it's used.

It is not as simple as that. Even if the c'tor is package-private, it can still be reached via reflection, and instances can still be created. This can possibly break a lot of code (I know - reflection shouldn't be used, but the reality is that it is used).

@Turing85 "reflection shouldn't be used" [citation needed] :)

@Glorfindel it is a pain when using native compilation with GraalVM. It breaks code navigation and refactoring. It is more often than not a workaround for a deeper problem. It hurts performance. It prevents compiler optimizations (probably not relevant in the HotSpotVM, but relevant when comiling natively). I cannot list all sources, but here are some: https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-benefits-drawbacks -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425906/is-java-reflection-bad-practice - https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-reflection-performance. I am sure you can find more.

So you think nothing should ever be refactored because someone, somewhere might be using reflection to break encapsulation? You’re quite the conservative, aren’t you? To be clear, I think the reason was to save time fully thinking through the implications of changing the one place where this constructor is used.
